# Two different post types in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table in the database:

posts table

```
id|name|message|time
```

notification table

```
id|name|initiator|type|message|time
```

What I want is two output both of the tables mix not one after another.

something like this:

```
Simon: Reebal want to be friends? 5 minutes ago
Reebal: Yeah sure. 4 minutes ago
Simon and Reebal are friends now (notification)
Reebal: How are you? 2 minutes ago
Simon: Fine and you? 1 minute ago
```

and not like this:

```
Simon and Reebal are friends now (notification)
Simon: Reebal want to be friends? 5 minutes ago
Reebal: Yeah sure. 4 minutes ago
Reebal: How are you? 2 minutes ago
Simon: Fine and you? 1 minute ago
```

Is it possible to do this? I hope you understand what I mean?
And please no full code, just a advice to the right way.

Comment: What have you tried? It's hard to help without any meat on the bone. Please give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Advice :

You should use union in both queries to get the result.

UNION keyword

Comment: This is not an answer, this is just a comment.

Comment: But quitioner have just asked for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION for this.

```
select * from (
    SELECT name, '' as initiator, '' as type, message, time from post
    UNION
    SELECT name, initiator, type, message, time from notification
) as data order by time desc
```

This should work for you

Comment: thanks for your answer I read I little bit about UNION, but another question: how can i style the notification output and the posts output differently? they should not look the same?

Comment: You should add one additional tag to recognize the action. I have added 1 new tag as action with this tag you can easily style the notification OR post.

select * from (
    SELECT name, '' as initiator, '' as type, message, time, 'post' as action from post
    UNION
    SELECT name, initiator, type, message, time,  'notification' as action from notification
) as data order by time desc